# Is it possible to see which processes were running when the PC crashed last time?

Tags: arch-linux, kde, file-transfer

I was in the middle of a file-transfer about an hour ago and, when I came back after a while, the PC had crashed, so I'd like to see if all the files were transferred successfully.

I'm using Arch + KDE.

**EDIT:** I just used plain old `dolphin` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. I have a TrueNAS set up, which runs ZFS RAIDZ2, so I just enabled NFS shares and mounted it on my desktop PC.

Comment: How (what command(s)) did you launch your file transfer ? Just asking because unless getting a script copying each file individually one after the other, I fail to realize how answering your question as worded in the title would help you in your quest as explained.

Comment: I've added an edit to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to see which processes were running at the time of the crash would be if you had `kdump` or some other crash-dump mechanism set up ahead of time, and the dump was actually performed successfully. Then you could use the `ps` command of the `crash` utility to get the list of processes at the time the crash happened.

A mounted NFS filesystem is supposed to be a very close equivalent to a local filesystem. But you apparently were doing a *move* operation *from one filesystem to another*, which is always going to be implemented as a copy+delete, and any sane implementation will delete the original only *after* the copy has been successfully completed.

So, if the transferred files are no longer present in their original location, you can be sure that the files were successfully transferred; if the copying part of the operation were interrupted, one or more of the files would still be present at the original location.

Comment: I've updated the question. Please have a look.